# How to add multiple labels in a view in swift, by pushing a button?

Tags: swift, label, chat

I've just started to learn Swift and I want to do a simple chat application.
I've started with the chat view, and for the beginning, to get me used with the language, I want to be able to make a conversation with myself.
**For example**, if I write a message and press the `send button` to display it on the *left* side of the screen, and if I write another message and press the `send button` to display it on the *right* side of the screen, and so on ...

So far I just can take a text from my `input` and put it into a `label` (and I made my frame and my keyboard to be responsive).

 What I don't know how to do !? :

- I want after I click the button to make another `label`, and display it after the last one, in the other part of the screen ... (cl: I want to create a lable for each message I send)

Here is my code until now, I've searched on the internet but so far I could not find something helpful ... I will appreciate any kind of tip...

Thank you!

```
                    //my label
                    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
                    //my text field
                    @IBOutlet weak var textF: UITextField!


                    //we move the frame up and down with 250 when the keyboard appears
                    override func viewDidLoad() {
                        super.viewDidLoad()
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
                    }

                    //show keyboard
                    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
                        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 250
                    }


                    //things TODO when the user is pressing the button
                    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

                        //create a variable(input) to store my text from the TextField
                        var input = textF.text
                        //put that text in the label
                        label.text = input

                        //empty text field
                        textF.text = " "

                        //create a new label for a new message
                        var label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 21))

                        // set the new label equal with the first to put the new message in it
                        //label2 = label

                        label2.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
                        label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                        label2.text = "I'am a test label"



                        //add it to the view
                        self.view.addSubview(label2)


                        //hide the keyboard
                       // self.textF.resignFirstResponder()
                    }

                    //hide keyboard if you tap the screen
                    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
                        self.view.endEditing(true)
                    }

                    //hide keyboard and get down the view
                    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
                        self.view.frame.origin.y += 250
                    }
```

Comment: Use a tableView and use 2 custom tableViewCell one with leftLabel another with rightLabel. when u press on the button u add cell which u want and reload the cell or tableview. u have to set the cell height dynamically based on entering text

Answer (score 1):

> *** Try Below Code  ***

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
//my text field
@IBOutlet weak var textF: UITextField!
var label2 : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 21))
var isSendMessage: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if isSendMessage {
            var input = textF.text
            label.text = input
            textF.text = " "

        } else {
            var input = textF.text
            label2.text = input
            textF.text = " "

        }
    }
}


//we move the frame up and down with 250 when the keyboard appears
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    label2.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label2)
}

//show keyboard
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 250
}


//things TODO when the user is pressing the button
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    isSendMessage = !isSendMessage

     self.textF.resignFirstResponder()
}

//hide keyboard if you tap the screen
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//hide keyboard and get down the view
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 250
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a little bit ! I moved one step ahead... I did not know abut 'didSet' .

Comment: its act like property observers. when ever you set that variable this didSet call